# Solving a hyperbolic equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have the following equation:

```
    Tanh[-19.4*\[Zeta]]*Exp[k x] == Tanh[-19.4*\[Psi]];
    \[Zeta] = 66;
    k x = 9.21;
```

I want to calculate the value of `\[Psi]` by using this above equation. I used the Solve command

```
 Solve[Tanh[-19.4*\[Zeta]]*Exp[k x] == Tanh[-19.4*\[Psi]], \[Psi]]
```

But it shows the error like:

Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found;    use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

**Question**

> How do I solve this equation.

Please help me. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Replacing  -19.4 with $\sigma$ and solving yields

```
eqn = Tanh[-\[Sigma]*\[Zeta]]*Exp[k x] == Tanh[-\[Sigma]*\[Psi]]
Solve[eqn, \[Psi]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

which seems about right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `k x` in `k x =9.21` should read `kx` without space. Then it is a good idea to rationalize the constants. With this we get:

```
\[Zeta] = 66;
kx = 921/100;
Solve[Tanh[-194/10*\[Zeta]]*Exp[kx] == Tanh[-194/10*\[Psi]], \[Psi]]
```

[image]

or numerical:

[image]